# query about pdf file

Tags: java

How can i append 2nd page of a pdf file to the first page.
in my case the page is getting overwritten..plz reply soon

Comment: blah.. what are you using, what is your current code, what have you tried. Do you expect someone to guess all these so that he is able to provide a meaningful answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfCopy(document,new FileOutputStream("e:\\new1.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfImportedPage page; 
document.newPage(); 
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) { 
  page = writer.getImportedPage(reader,i); 
  ((PdfCopy) writer).addPage(page); 
}
```

Comment: Edit your original question and format the code correctly. If you don't know how, take a look at the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are generating the PDF, but better use [iText PDF](http://itextpdf.com/), helps you generate, split, merge and manipulate PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

PdfWriter writer = new PdfCopy(document,new FileOutputStream("e:\new1.pdf")); document.open(); PdfImportedPage page; document.newPage(); for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) { page = writer.getImportedPage(reader,i); ((PdfCopy) writer).addPage(page); }

How this works?